# Laravel: cannot save/open temporary file when merging pdfs

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [this plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/grofgraf/laravel-pdf-merger) for merging PDFs in laravel

Whenever I am merging files I am getting the below error

> fopen(/path/tmp/file.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I am using vagrantbox (centos 7) as environment for running laravel.

I have tried a few other plugins. I am stuck with the same problem in all of them.

EDIT: the path shown is an example. The tmp directory created by the plugin does exist. The temporary file that was supposed to be inside that folder however does not.

Comment: Does that file path exist? Confirm that it is in your project. It seems generic to me

Comment: that's an example path. The path in the original message does exist

Comment: so the path was created by the plugin, but it still says it doesn't exist? -- you just edited and said the directory is there but the file isn't

Comment: Sorry, by path I meant directory. The directory tmp is created by the plugin. However the temporary file that was supposed to be inside it do not exist. Either the file is being deleted faster than the plugin can read it or it is never being saved.